# Airflow Batch Operator, Use Fargate Spot but run retries on Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, aws-fargate, aws-batch

I have a collection of DAGS in Airflow that run heavy tasks using AWS Batch FARGATE, and I'm interested in using Spot for most runs to reduce cost, but would like to run retries without spot to avoid the possibility of dag failures from back to back spot interruptions.

Currently I use 2 different JobQueues, on with a spot compute environment, and the other with a regular fargate compute environment.

Is there a way in airflow to have the BatchOperator use a different JobQueue on retries.